# How do I convert a mention variable, to a normal variable and print it to my terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

I have a variable in my code that looks like this, only problem is it looks very ugly in my terminal. Here's a picture.

[image: My temrminal]

I would like it to display: **{Name of the winner} has won: {prize}**, instead of showing their Discord ID and making my terminal look horrible to look at.

Here is my code, which makes this monstrosity of a terminal.

```
winners = random.sample([user for user in users if not user.bot], k=winerscount)

winnerstosend = "\n".join([winner.mention for winner in winners])




win = await msg.edit(embed = discord.Embed(title = "WINNER" , description = f"Congratulations {winnerstosend}, you have won **{msg4.content}**!" , color = discord.Color.blue()))

print(Fore.GREEN + winnerstosend , Fore.WHITE + "has won: " , Fore.GREEN + msg4.content)
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
```

Now I would love it if you could help me out, and convert my mistake into a beautiful confirmation message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, try `winner.display_name` instead of `winner.mention`

Answer (score 1):

Is user your object?
If so, you can define a [**str** dunder-method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) and print the string in the way you want.

Please see example below.

```
user@Inspiron:~/code/advanced_python$ cat str_dunder_example.py 
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return f'User {self.name} aged {self.age} has won'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A('FakeBlob', 20)
    print(a)
user@Inspiron:~/code/advanced_python$ python str_dunder_example.py 
User FakeBlob aged 20 has won
user@Inspiron:~/code/advanced_python$
```

Comment: i don't get what your trying to ask. @ll

Comment: Class of winnerstosend object is defined by you?

Comment: You can convert to a class and have it printed in customized manner you like by  defining __str__ as illustrated above.